# Finding Unknown variable "x" that satisfies two mod conditions

Tags: r, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was wondering how to find the smallest integer "x," that satisfies two mod conditions.

```
    x%%7 == 1
    x%%10 == 2
```

I have attempted to use for/while loops within a function, like so with no such luck:

```
  min.integer <- function(x) {
    y = c(1:500000)
    for (i in y) {
      if (x%%10 == 2) {
        print(x)
      } else {
        break
      }     
    }
  }
```

Is this the best way to approach this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Tagged [tag:Chinese-remainder-theorem]. You know there's an algorithm to get an analytical solution, right? So no need for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple while loop

```
m=n=0
x=1
while(!(m==1&n==2)){
  x=x+1
  m=x%%7
  n=x%%10
}
x
22
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
twoModsSatisfied <- function(
    mod1
    , equals1
    , mod2
    , equals2
    , howMany # how many different values do you want to try
){
    x <- (0:howMany) * mod1 # all these values will satify the 1st condition
    x[which((x + equals1) %% mod2 == equals2)][1] + equals1
}

twoModsSatisfied(
    7
    , 1
    , 10
    , 2
    , 100
)
```

The `[1]` makes sure you only get the first value that satisfies the condition. `0:howMany` makes sure you get the correct result for `twoModsSatisfied(7,2,10,2,100)`. The function doesn't check if the request is impossible (e.g. `twoModsSatisfied(7,8,10,2,100)`), but this can be done easily as well using an `if`statement.